# Parse android SDK 1.9.1 Find Callback

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, sdk

I was using sdk 1.8.2 which had callback something like this :

```
commentObjectsQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(List list, ParseException e) {

        }
    });
```

And now in sdk 1.9.1 they have this:

```
commentObjectsQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(List list, ParseException e) {

        }
        @Override
        public void done(Object o, Throwable throwable) {

        }
    });
```

What is the second done method for?

**Update:**

I tried cleaning the project but no luck.

it shows this error while compiling:

```
Error:(107, 65) error: <anonymous com.pickup.pickrup.activities.CommentActivity$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method done(Object,Throwable) in ParseCallback2
```

Comment: Is it not documented? In the [docs](http://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/FindCallback.html) there's no second method

Comment: @Lamorak Document is not updated I guess, using sdk 1.9.1 if you try to compile, it gives an error that Findcallback must implement the other method too

Comment: Oh well.. So you can ask in Parse help community. Also try to examine when those methods are called by logging. Probably nothing more can be done..

Comment: I'm on Parse 1.9.1 and I'm not getting any compilation error by having only the first done() method. Maybe try cleaning your project? Not sure.

Comment: @Urban It's only happening with Findcallback. I tried cleaning it but it shows the error while building the project. Please take a look at the updated question. I'll also post this on Parse Google group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be because you are not specifying the generic parameter.

For instance if you are querying the Comment class , use:

```
 ParseQuery<Comment> query = new ParseQuery<Comment>("Comment");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Comment>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<Comment> comments, ParseException e) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: How do I know what generic parameter to query for?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky any class you made that inherits from ParseObject. Depends on what the query is about